# disappearing GUI java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Im tryin to get my GUI to work its a drop down menu

the first 2 options work but then the second 2 don't...

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class starter 
    {
        public static void main (String [] args)
        {
            Object[] menuItems1 = {"Login as Admin", "Login as Course Leader", "Login as Lecturer", "Login as  Student", "Quit"};
            Object selectedValue1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Choose one", 
                    "Input", 2, null, menuItems1, menuItems1[0]);
            boolean continuePlaying = true;
            if (selectedValue1 == null || selectedValue1.equals("Quit"))
                continuePlaying = false;
            else if (selectedValue1 == null || selectedValue1.equals("Login as Admin"))
            {

//this works 
                adminMenu a = new adminMenu();
                a.adminMenu();
            }
            else if (selectedValue1.equals("Login as Course Leader"))
            {
//and this works
                courseLeaderMenu b = new courseLeaderMenu();
                b.courseLeaderMenu();
            }
            else if (selectedValue1.equals("Login as  Lecturer"))
            {
//but this and
                lecturerMenu c = new lecturerMenu();
                c.lecturerMenu();
            }
            else if (selectedValue1.equals("Login as Student"))
            {
// this don't
                studentMenu d = new studentMenu();
                d.studentMenu();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appriciated, these menu options would lead into other ones obviously using the different classes that I have called here... Everything compiles perfectly but those last 2 options dont show anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have double spaces in the string from this if statement

```
else if (selectedValue1.equals("Login as  Lecturer"))
```

And in the "Login as Student" string at this line

```
Object[] menuItems1 = {"Login as Admin", "Login as Course Leader", "Login as Lecturer", "Login as  Student", "Quit"};
```

Comment: Thanks! Was drivin me crazy and I didnt see it!

Comment: @user3029733 It might be better to compare the selected value directly with the values in the array, this will prevent these types of errors